# Arcore: Loss plane when come out of the Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Arcore lost every plane when come out of Activity(Exemple: go to Preferences Activity for modify a parameter). Who cause the issue to see my GameObject linked to anchors to dissapears of the Camera.

I am on a Android Studio project where i have a Unity project exported on the first.
Everything work on the main activity with Arcore for searching planes.

I know than Unity do not lost data when i come back on my main Activity(The Anchor and GameObject keep the good position)

I have not found any means to keep the planes of ARCore between activity or when i standby the activity(switch to a another apk for qew seconds per example), so i put my problem here. What i have go wrong?